# Even space between elements in bootsrap's row, aligned left and right

Tags: html, css

I want to make those three divs take whole width of the parent div and have even space between them. How do I do that? Like on the pic below:

[image]

```html
<div class="media-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading"> {{ userprofile.user.username }}</h2>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.bio|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.city }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-link icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.website|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt icon-position"></i>
                <p class="text-secondary ">{{ userprofile.user.date_joined|date:"F Y" }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Posts: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Followers: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Following: 0
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div class="media-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading"> {{ userprofile.user.username }}</h2>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.bio|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
    <div class="row content-between">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.city }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-link icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.website|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt icon-position"></i>
                <p class="text-secondary ">{{ userprofile.user.date_joined|date:"F Y" }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content-between">
        <div class="col">
            Posts: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Followers: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Following: 0
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.content-between{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
}
```

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't need to create custom css property. Bootstrap4 already give class.

Please use `d-flex justify-content-end`. For more info [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/](http://Bootstrap%20Flex)

Let me know further clarification.

Hope it will help you. :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="media-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading"> {{ userprofile.user.username }}</h2>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.bio|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.city }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-link icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.website|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt icon-position"></i>
                <p class="text-secondary " style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end">{{ userprofile.user.date_joined|date:"F Y" }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Posts: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Followers: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
            Following: 0
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behaviour with flexbox.

In your .css:

```
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.col {
 width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row flex-container">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.city }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-link icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.website|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt icon-position"></i>
                <p class="text-secondary ">{{ userprofile.user.date_joined|date:"F Y" }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want the bottom row (Posts, Followers, Following) be aligned with the divs on top of them, just put them in the same row and divs and apply the same css to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="media-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading"> {{ userprofile.user.username }}</h2>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.bio|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.city }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fas fa-link icon-position"></i>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ userprofile.website|render_tags_and_links }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt icon-position"></i>
                <p class="text-secondary " style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end">{{ userprofile.user.date_joined|date:"F Y" }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Posts: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Followers: 0
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end">
            Following: 0
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I just added this line style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end"